# Grow raid5 lvm by adding extra disks

Tags: raid, lvm

I have 3 drives that I want in raid5 to get the most space utilization while still allowing a disk failure.  But I want to be able to expand the array later when I have more disks (likely up to 7 disks)

So if I initially create a raid5 array using pv/vg/lvm, can I later expand it by adding a 4th, 5th, etc. disk?

The array is a backup array, not a live array, so load is not an issue.

Comment: Please try not to use R5, especially with larger disk - it's been heavily-discouraged for over a decade now

Comment: @Chopper3 any reason/reading material as to why?

Comment: There's SO much out there - it's borderline negligent for it still to be available tbh - this is literally the first one that came up but there are so many - https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  RAID 5 logical volume with LVM and please use this below article for more reference.

[RAID 5 LVM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/raid_volumes)

Answer (score 0):

Using lvm for raid5 is generally a terrible idea. You should consider using the appropriate raid controller for that, or using zfs.

As about the expanding: usually raid 5 aren't expanding adding more disks in the raid group after some treshold (because this increases the ***cold data*** probability and the need to scrub the entire array more often). They are converting/expanding in/to the raid 50 by adding more raid 1 spans into it. Say you have 3 disks in the raid 5: then you could add 4th or even 5th disk into it, if the controller allows this, but adding 6th or 7th disk is then a bad idea. You should convert it to a raid 50 instead, adding the exact number off disks as a span: it means if you already have 5 disks, you should then add 5 more in a span, making it raid 50.